# How to select accounts in a dropdown dynamically using Correlation in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have account dropdown which consists of different accounts for different users. Whenever a user login it should pick the account dynamically (for 1 time 0048852 and next time 2752271) from the drop down. How to achieve this condition using Correlation. Here I'm attaching the .csv file which I have configured and Regular expression details. Please go through this and let me know if anything is required. Suggested me the best possible solution.
[Account_From_UI_For_one_User](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56Rvi.png), [Accounts_Selection_Declaration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqWN2.png), [CSV_Data_Set_Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkyhH.png), [CSV_File_Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvmGs.png), [Regular_Expression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIXhs.png)

Answer (score 0):

If the accounts change for each user, you can use "-1" as your Match No instead of "0" in your Regex Selector, which means select all instead of select a random account. After selecting all, you can just create a random number within the range of "1<yourMatchNoCount" and choose a random account. Or you can put the results in an array by using an array function and can test all of them as well.

Other solution to select all accounts for all users is, you can use a loop to change your Match No dynamic (${dynamic} instead of "0") and increase your Match No for each loop count. And when your Match No is greater than your results Account is going to be NotFound so you can control that as well.

Comment: Can you please give me an idea with the screenshots for the above cases. I will give a try and confirm.